# problem: zip files in mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

i am using SharpZipLib. i copied code from

[link text](http://www.eggheadcafe.com/tutorials/aspnet/9ce6c242-c14c-4969-9251-af95e4cf320f/zip--unzip-folders-and-files-with-c.aspx)

i use it to zip files in my App_Data folder. All goes right but when i want to delete files i can not do it. it says
teh action can't be completed because the file is open in another program. i can not solve this problem. please help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just a shot in the dark: The sample code opens a file to Zip with

```
ostream = File.OpenRead(Fil);
```

but it never gets closed.

```
ostream.Close()
```

or better

```
using(ostream = File.OpenRead(Fil)) 
{
}
```

Comment: wooow. You are great. It worked. i looked for it before but can not found where the problem was. but you have found it .Thanks